# changing height and width of imageview in android

Tags: android, layout, height, imageview, width

in my application on button click i want to change size of imageview.when i click on one button i want to increase size of imageview by 5(each width and height).and on clicking of other button i want to decrease the size.i tried this.
how can i do this?below is the code.its not working

```
 public void increase(View v)
{

    int height=imageView.getHeight();
    int width=imageView.getWidth();
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = height+5;
    int h=imageView.getHeight();
    System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhh,,,,,,,,,,"+h);
    System.out.println("width n hight..."+width+"and"+height);


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Do this:

```
int height=imageView.getHeight();
int width=imageView.getWidth();
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, width));
```

Suggesting your ImageView is located inside a LinearLayout you need to do this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.setHeight(XX);
params.setWidth(XX);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I don't know if the syntax is perfectly correct, but basically this is how you do it, don't forget that you need to update your UI, in order to see any changes.

Comment: at each time on button click i want to increase by 5

Comment: you just need to set the new height/width: params.setHeight(height + 5) and height can you get with the call you already defined: int height=imageView.getHeight();

Comment: there is no method setHeight n width  for the type params

Comment: hey actually i was trying 2nd code.but now i tried 1st caode.its really working.thank you so much.

Comment: There is no such method as setWidth and setHeight for params. Please update your answer.

Comment: I am not sure about the second approach, I have not checked it again but I am pretty sure the first approach will still work

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code for it:

```
your_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

Hope it helps u..

you can try the following alternate approach.. see if it works:

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 120;
params.height = 120;

imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Although both the codes are almost same...

Comment: its not working.i tried it - ' int h=imageView.getHeight();
  int w=imageView.getWidth();
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = h+5;
  imageView.getLayoutParams().width=w+5; '

Comment: is there any exception coming ?

Comment: you can try the following alternate approach.. see if it works